# Hello, I am trying to use wildcard query with filters in elastric search in my node js application

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting search item from user as

```
let eventSearch="*"+event.SearchTerm+"*";
```

This is the query object

```
   let queryObject =
    {  
        index: 'mark_deling_test2',
        type: 'product',
        body: {
            "from" : event.StartIndex, "size" : event.ResultSize,
            "query": {
                "filtered":{
                    "query":{
                      "query_string":{
                         "fields":     [ "Name^2.5", "Description", "keywords^1.75" ],
                         "query":eventSearch,
                         "analyze_wildcard":true

                        }
                    },
                    "filter":{
                        "term":{
                          "groups": "CA-IBO"
                        } 
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    };
```

Then sending this query object for searching

This is not working. If I don't use the filter it works. 
Please Help!

Comment: Does it work when you remove the "groups": "CA-IBO" filter condition? Add the query that works to provide more info about the issue.

Comment: Yes. It works if I remove the filter.

Comment: This Works:
    {  
            index: 'mark_deling_test2',
            type: 'product',
            body:{
                "from" : event.StartIndex, "size" : event.ResultSize,
                "query":{
                  "query_string":{
                     "fields":     [ "Name^2.5", "Description", "keywords^1.75" ],
                     "query":eventSearch,
                     "analyze_wildcard":true

                    }
                }
            }
        };

Comment: Since the filter is the issue, have you verified if there are matching data for that filter?

Comment: Yes there is matching data for filter. I actually figured it out. Had to use "bool" and "must"

Comment: Add the correct query as an answer. it will help others who get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get mark_deling_test2/_search
  {
   “query”: {
  “bool”: {
    “must”: {
      “query_string”: {
         “query”: “nut*“,
         “fields”: [“Name”, “Description”, “keywords”]
       }
     },
     “filter”: {
       “term”: {
     “groups”: “US-IBO”
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```